# executing for loop on windows with python command

Tags: windows, shell

I want to convert many files using python routines. the name of the files are p0, p1, p2,..., p10, ...p100, txt extension. I use the following routine:

py_odt.py input_file.txt outputfile.dat

in cmd i write:

```
 For /R  %i in (*.txt) do py_odt.py  *.txt *.dat %i
```

The problem is that the input part of py_odt.py does not recognize the input file, what I can put in the input file for the code recognize the txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you are trying to execute `py_odt.py <name>.txt <name>.dat` where `<name>` is in `p0, p1, ... p100`. I suppose you are using `sys.argv` in python to collect the args.

The issue here is that the args you give to your python script are not valid file paths : `*.txt` and `*.dat`. What you must do is extract the name of the file using `%~ni`. I don't use Windows so I cannot test it, but you can try this instead:

```
For /R %i in (*.txt) do py_odt.py "%i" "%~ni.dat"
```

*Don't forget to replace `%i` by `%%i` in a batch file.*